# flask basic authentication with apache mod_wsgi

Tags: python, apache, authentication, flask, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to use apache mod_wsgi to create a daemon process with a python flask application. I want to authenticate credentials in *some* of my url paths. Here is the app flaskapp.py

```
from flask import Flask
import flask_httpauth

app = Flask(__name__)
auth = flask_httpauth.HTTPBasicAuth()

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
  return 'Hello from flaskapp.py!'
@app.route('/private')
@auth.login_required
def check_credentials():
    if auth.username()=='myself': 
        if password == 'secret': 
            return 'Valid'
        else: return 'Wrong'
    return None

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run()
```

I've added a WSGI daemon section in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf as follows:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess flaskapp threads=5
WSGIScriptAlias /flaskapp /var/www/html/flaskapp/flaskapp.wsgi
WSGIPassAuthorization On

<Directory flaskapp>
    WSGIProcessGroup flaskapp
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

The flaskapp.wsgi file:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/html/flaskapp')
from flaskapp import app as application
```

When I try to access these URLs in a REST client (chrome),

- the URL /flaskapp works with a "hello from flaskapp.py" as desired.
- with the URL  /flaskapp/private, I get a authentication login form. After filling the username and password, it does not pass it on to the check_credentials() function in flaskapp.py. Each time the REST client gets 401 Unauthorized and repeats the login credentials form.
- I have WSGIPassAuthorization On
- Without mod_wsgi, as a plain Flask application, the same code works with a single request for credentials.

So the flaskapp.py module works (with @auth.login) as a plain flask application, but does not work as expected - inside a mod_wsgi Daemon process.

The app runs on an AWS EC2 Ubuntu instance.

Any idea what is going wrong?

Update: (Thank you @Graham Dumpleton). Added logging as suggested:

```
class LoggingMiddleware:

def __init__(self, application):
    self.__application = application

def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
    errors = environ['wsgi.errors']
    pprint.pprint(('REQUEST', environ), stream=errors)

    def _start_response(status, headers, *args):
        pprint.pprint(('RESPONSE', status, headers), stream=errors)
        return start_response(status, headers, *args)

    return self.__application(environ, _start_response)

application = LoggingMiddleware(app.app_context())
```

Now the apache error log is as follows:

```
'REQUEST',
{'CONTENT_TYPE': 'application/json',
 'CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT': '/var/www/html',
 'CONTEXT_PREFIX': '',
 'DOCUMENT_ROOT': '/var/www/html',
 'GATEWAY_INTERFACE': 'CGI/1.1',
 'HTTP_HOST': 'ec2-nn-nn-nnn-nnn.us-xxxx-n.compute.amazonaws.com',
 'PATH_INFO': '/private',
 'PATH_TRANSLATED': '/var/www/html/private',
 'QUERY_STRING': '',
 'REMOTE_ADDR': '122.167.143.128',
 'REMOTE_PORT': '12810',
 'REQUEST_METHOD': 'GET',
 'REQUEST_SCHEME': 'http',
 'REQUEST_URI': '/flaskapp/private',
 'SCRIPT_FILENAME': '/var/www/html/flaskapp/flaskdbgapp.wsgi',
 'SCRIPT_NAME': '/flaskapp',
 'SERVER_ADDR': 'nnn.nn.nn.nnn',
 'SERVER_ADMIN': 'webmaster@localhost',
 'SERVER_NAME': 'ec2-nn-nn-nnn-nnn.us-xxxx-n.compute.amazonaws.com',
 'SERVER_PORT': '80',
 'SERVER_PROTOCOL': 'HTTP/1.1',
 'SERVER_SIGNATURE': '<address>Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at ec2-nn-nn-nnn-nnn.us-xxxx-2.compute.amazonaws.com Port 80</address>\\n',
 'SERVER_SOFTWARE': 'Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)',
 'mod_wsgi.application_group': 'ip-nnn-nn-nn-nnn.us-xxxx-2.compute.internal|/flaskapp',
 'mod_wsgi.callable_object': 'application',
 'mod_wsgi.enable_sendfile': '0',
 'mod_wsgi.handler_script': '',
 'mod_wsgi.input_chunked': '0',
 'mod_wsgi.listener_host': '',
 'mod_wsgi.listener_port': '80',
 'mod_wsgi.process_group': '',
 'mod_wsgi.queue_start': '1489237814187968',
 'mod_wsgi.request_handler': 'wsgi-script',
 'mod_wsgi.script_reloading': '1',
 'mod_wsgi.version': (3, 4),
 'wsgi.errors': <mod_wsgi.Log object at 0x7f0d96a77f30>,
 'wsgi.file_wrapper': <built-in method file_wrapper of mod_wsgi.Adapter object at 0x7f0d96a79990>,
 'wsgi.input': <mod_wsgi.Input object at 0x7f0d96a77a30>,
 'wsgi.multiprocess': True,
 'wsgi.multithread': True,
 'wsgi.run_once': False,
 'wsgi.url_scheme': 'http',
 'wsgi.version': (1, 0)})
'RESPONSE',
'401 UNAUTHORIZED',
[('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8'),
 ('Content-Length', '19'),
 ('WWW-Authenticate', 'Basic realm="Authentication Required"')])
```

Still no clue to a solution :-(

Comment: Are you sure Apache was restarted after ``WSGIPassAuthorization`` was added? Try http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/debugging-techniques.html#displaying-request-environment to see if the required header values are in fact passed to the WSGI application.

Comment: @Graham Dumpleton. Thank you for the tip and link. a) yes, i restarted the apache server.  b) Tried the debug code in the link. It works beautifully. c) Yet, I can't integrate it with my flaskapp.py code to get similar results. The problem is that my "app =  Flask(__name__)" object does not have the the signature that "application(environ, start_response)" has.

Comment: Keep reading down in the same document and look at other examples, specifically what is in http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/debugging-techniques.html#tracking-request-and-response

Comment: I am facing the exact same problem right now. Did you find a solution you'd care to share?

Comment: - @harminica141 no, I couldn't find a solution :-(   tried hard to find some answers with variations to my scripts. No dice. My flask app now runs in "developer mode" and is none the worse for it.